# Lightweight bash script

Tags: bash

I have a text file (test.dat) with data like this

```
time    value1 value2
00:09:20 10 20
--
time    value3 number4
00:09:20 30 40
--
```

I need to extract the values in the columns value1, value2, value3 and number4 and output like

```
10:20:30:40

cat test.dat |
grep -A 1 -w 'value1\|value2\|value3\|number4' |
sed 's/--/\n/g' |
sed '/^$/d' |
awk 'NR%2==0' |
awk '{$1=""; print}' |
tr -d "\n"|
awk '{print $1 ":" $2 ":" $3 ":" $4}'
```

But this is taking lot of time. Is there a lightweight way to get this approach.

Comment: If this is taking a long time, how many files are you processing?

Comment: First things first, you can drop the `cat` and just `grep` the file directly

Comment: @nneonneo, this is just one file but I need to execute this script many times.

Comment: You can certainly combine some of the individual commands in the pipeline. Not just the cat, but most of the rest could be a single awk or sed command.

Comment: @kojiro, I am thinking of the same to club these multiple commands into one assuming piping is consuming too much time

Comment: Whenever you use `grep`, `sed` and `awk` together, you can usually drop `grep` and `sed` and just do everything with `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v OFS=: 'NR%3 == 2 {print $2, $3}' test.dat | paste -sd:
10:20:30:40
```

Comment: The portable way is `paste -sd: -` the implicit stdin works only in GNU version.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -nE 's/[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:]]+) ([[:digit:]]+)/\1:\2/p'
```

will do what you are asking for, then you need to pipe the result into

```
tr "\n" ":"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use sed or awk?
If the file format is always the same, you can use:

```
while read line; do
    if [ "${line:0:4}" == "time" ]; then
        read number
        outText="${outText}$(echo "$number"|cut -d' ' -f2-|tr ' ' ':'):"
    fi
done<test.dat
outText=${outText%:} # Remove last unuseful :
echo "$outText"
```

Comment: @Nemo: you're right but cut and tr are really "light" in respect to sed and awk ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `grep`, `sed` and `awk` together, you can usually drop grep and `sed` and just do everything with `awk`.

```
awk '/^[0-9]/ { if ( ! printed ) {
        printf $2 ":" $3
        printed=1
    }
        else {
        printf ":" $2 ":" $3
    }
}' test.txt
```